# Alternatives to MultiView in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multiview

The website I'm building contains a large number of views which will be displayed on the same place but hidden or shown according to how the user navigates the menu.

It gets quite messy in visual studios design view when you have a MultiView with 10 different views in it. I've already separated the content of each view in several user controls. But is there an alternative to MultiView?

Comment: why you can use wizard in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I generally just use a Panel or Placeholder and toggle visibilities manually.  But then I don't use the VS designer either...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ASP.NET webforms here...

This is another reason to invest in some powerful web controls like the Telerik ASP.NET control suite.

You could use their RadTabStrip control along with the RadMultiPage control.

Example here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/multipage/loading-external-content/defaultcs.aspx

You can specify a ContentUrl for each RadPageView which allows you to separate each view into separate aspx files.

This simplifies your solution by separating each view into their own page and increases performance as RadPageView content is requested only when viewed initially.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would do this would be to have a placeholder on the page and dynamically add controls to it as needed.

From what you have said it looks like the user navigates a menu and this decides which view to display in the MultiView control...

I would so something like this

ASPX file:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id=phContentContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Code Behind

```
switch (MenuSelection)
{
     case "LOGIN" //Display the login control
     {
        ucLoginUserControlType loginControl = (ucLoginUserControlType)LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucLoginUserControlType.ascx");

        phContentContainer.Controls.Add(loginControl);
     }
}
```

Obviously you will want to work the codebehind to be a bit more efficient and cleaner than the above would be with 10 views... but you get the idea.

This keeps your aspx page simple and makes future control additions easier to implement.

Hope this helps, I have typed the code from memory, so some syntax may not be right - if you cant get it going give me a shout and Ill dig out some examples of when I have done this.

Good luck!